# Python Mock: Result of method call is __getitem__ instead of actual value

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a unit test and mocking an external call. Here's the abbreviated code for the function I'm trying to test in service.py file

```
def post_data()
  req = request.Request()
  response = req.post(payload, url, json.dumps({"data": kwargs['data']}))

  if response['request']['status'] == 'SUCCESS' and response['data']:
      run_id = response.json()['data']['run_id']
      response = track_run_to_completion(run_id, **kwargs)

  return response
```

Here's my unit test method

```
@patch('service.request.Request.post')
    def test_post_data(self, mock_post):
        kwargs = {'a':'abc'}
        expected = json.dumps({'request':{'status':'ERROR'},'data':{}})
        mock_post.return_value = MagicMock(status_code=200, response=expected)
mock_post.assert_called_once_with({'action': 'trigger'}, 'a/abc', '{"data": {}}') # SUCCESS!
            result = service.post_data(**kwargs)
            print result
```

When I print the result, I was expecting to see the json, but get `<MagicMock name='post()' id='4488707600'>`. What am I missing here? I'm new to Python and started writing unit tests for an existing application.